# xml files are not copied to target intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some xml files within the source folder along with the java files.
Intellij Idea is not copying them to the target folder.
I want those xml files to be along with the classes in the target.
Eclipse does this fine.

Can anyone please tell how to achieve this in Intellij Idea?

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Maven or Gradle or Ant?

Comment: Put your java under src/main/java, and your xml files under src/main/resources. Create a basic pom file in your project root, and have idea import this. Then everything will work. If you're trying to do anything else, then you're doing it the hard way and you're unlikely to get a lot of help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If, like me, the other answer didn't solve your problem -

If IDEA thinks your project is a Maven module (or once was), and it isn't, it'll behave like this. You can fix this by closing the project, editing the .iml file to remove the isMavenModule property, reopening, and rebuilding:

`<module`<s>`org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true"`</s>`type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">`

Comment: You prevented me from going to the asylum. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Pure genius.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In its default configuration, IDEA should copy any xml file that are in a source directory into the target directory. Other build tools may not. So this answer is assuming you are making the project via IDEA's internal build/make. If using maven (or gradle), you should place your resources in `src/main/resources` and **not** `src/main/java` as Engineer Dollery mentions in his/her comment.

If you are using the IDEA builds and it is still not copying them over, there is a setting you can check. Go into *Settings > Build, Execution, Development > Compiler*. On the *Compiler* settings dialog at the top is a "Resource Patterns" text field. This will define what files IDEA will and will not copy over. The default entry is:

```
    !?*.java
    !?*.form
    !?*.class
    !?*.groovy
    !?*.scala
    !?*.flex
    !?*.kt
    !?*.clj
    !?*.aj
```

It is just a set of negation patterns of things *not* to copy over. So XML files should be copied. Check this setting and see if there is something in it to prevent xml files from being copied.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers, about "Resource Patterns" and editing the .iml file, didn't solve my problem so continued to look around.

What I found to solve my problem was:

Open File - Project Structure

Under Project Settings select Modules

Under Sources expand the source tree to src\main\resources and Mark as: Resources

And src\test\resources Mark as: Test Resources
and press OK

After performing the above steps I saw that my *.xml from src\main\resources are now  copied to target\classes when I run a class via Idea Run Configuration.