# Tomcat throwing an error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Tomcat 7.0.59
Java 7

If I run my project for the first time it runs well.
But If I restart my computer I am having an error

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/connectionConf.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.metamodel.source.MappingException: Error accessing stax stream
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)....
```

Comment: Look here: org.hibernate.metamodel.source.MappingException: Error accessing stax stream. Maybe an  error in your XML file

Comment: The same same project running well on my friends machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be issues with your /WEB-INF/classes/connectionConf.xml class file or any hibernate related xml file, while all .java files are compiled and moved .xml files would not have been compiled . Just check.

Comment: I heard the same answer from other guys, but how to check if its been compiled

Comment: @ Nishh are you here?

Comment: @Nishh great it worked - thank you.

Actual problem is solved [from there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31077461/5842094), but the main idea is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is an error with database-java object mapping configuration, Check your mapping xml files make sure they are in line with db datatypes,columns,keys..etc

Answer (score 0):

while parsing **connectionConf.xml**, you are getting error. Recheck the mapping configuration.